# Set with modified lower box counting dimension strictly less than Hausdorff dimension

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Please, can someone give (as simple as possible) example of the set for which modified lower box counting dimension is strictly smaller than Hausdorff dimension?

Comment: What's modified lower box counting dimension?

Comment: I have found the solution: Claude Tricot: Two definitions of fractional dimension, Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society / Volume 91 / Issue 01 / January 1982, pp, 57-74, DOI: 10.1017/S0305004100059119. It is given by example 2 on page 67.

Comment: This dimension is also called lower packing dimension